# Android: java.io.IOException: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid distance too far back while fetching data from server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having issues on a code which was working very fine.
I am running an Async task to get data from web server in android, the issue is that when the control comes in the readLine in async task I am getting an exception, details are provided below:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
```

Stacktrace:

```
05-24 21:10:41.261 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err: java.io.IOException: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid distance too far back
05-24 21:10:41.263 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:84)
05-24 21:10:41.263 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
05-24 21:10:41.264 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:349)
05-24 21:10:41.265 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
05-24 21:10:41.266 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
05-24 21:10:41.268 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
05-24 21:10:41.270 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at com.fiesta.SearchPeople$1GetPeople.doInBackground(SearchPeople.java:131)
05-24 21:10:41.271 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at com.fiesta.SearchPeople$1GetPeople.doInBackground(SearchPeople.java:96)
05-24 21:10:41.272 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
05-24 21:10:41.273 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-24 21:10:41.275 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
05-24 21:10:41.276 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
05-24 21:10:41.277 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
05-24 21:10:41.279 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-24 21:10:41.280 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err: Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid distance too far back
05-24 21:10:41.282 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateImpl(Native Method)
05-24 21:10:41.283 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:237)
05-24 21:10:41.284 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:67)
05-24 21:10:41.285 11232-11476/com.fiesta W/System.err:     ... 13 more
```

I know that the data in php is not corrupted, I can see it is returning the object correctly.

```
    <?php
include 'includes/conn.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$u_id = $_GET['uid'];
$s = $_GET['s'];
$result = array();
$res = mysqli_query($con,"select u_id, first_name, last_name, user_profile_image from main_user_login where concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%$s%'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($result,
    array('u_id'=>$row['u_id'],
    'first_name'=>$row['first_name'],
    'last_name'=>$row['last_name'],
    'user_profile_image'=>$row['user_profile_image']
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

This issue is coming suddenly, I know this cannot be a code issue since there was no code change done and this issue started coming.
Please suggest.

Comment: Update, I tried running this on Nexus 6, it didn't work, but it worked fine on nexus 4.

Comment: were you able to find the solution to this? I am facing it too! @user3520457

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown when the data is parsed incorrectly may be.